# I am having problem when adding a working update button inside material ui datagrid v5.6.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I am trying to add a button inside my material ui datagrid row.

My datagrid component

```
<DataGrid
    rows={adminStorage}
    columns={columns}
    autoPageSize
    getRowId={(logistics) => logistics._id }
    autoHeight
    headerHeight={60}
    pageSize={100}
    className={classes.root}
/>
```

the column

```
    {
        ...
        field: "update",
        align:"left",
        headerAlign: "left",
        headerName: "Update",
        renderCell: (cellValues) => {
            return (
                <Button pL={2} onClick={updateHandler} variant="contained" color="primary">
                    update
                </Button>
            )
        }
    },
```

the update handler

```
const updateHandler = (cellvalues) => {
     console.log("The data botained fron the handler is", cellvalues)
}
```

I want it to work in such a way that when the button is clicked it links to another page that has edit form as well as getting that specific row object and its id

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

React is still javascript, according to react https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers you can

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.deleteRow(id, e)}>Delete Row</button>
<button onClick={this.deleteRow.bind(this, id)}>Delete Row</button>
```

> In both cases, the e argument representing the React event will be passed as a second argument after the ID. With an arrow function, we have to pass it explicitly, but with bind, any further arguments are automatically forwarded.

You can also retrieve further data from the clicked element by using the passed event and the target attribute
like

```
const updateHandler = (event) => {
     let element = event.target;

     console.log("The data botained fron the handler is", element.getAttribute("attribute"))
}
```

Comment: I am not getting the cell values when i log i am only getting SyntheticBaseEvent object

Comment: @FunStrike yes, that's what react uses https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html, you can use it to get the target element, attributes etc. I suggest you read the react documentation, you will save yourself a lot of time

Comment: @FunStrike Check the quoted text in the answer, the value is passed as the second parameter if you pass it to the onclick